# zeppelin_ipyspark.py at apache zeppelin get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, windows-10, apache-zeppelin

when i running code with pyspark in apache zeppelin 0.8.1 , i get error like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
```

...

so i open all file in my folder zeppelin

and i try to running file `zeppelin_ipyspark.py` at `D:\zeppelin-0.8.1-bin-all\interpreter\spark\python` with cmd

and i get error

```
D:\zeppelin-0.8.1-bin-all\interpreter\spark\python>zeppelin_ipyspark.py
  File "D:\zeppelin-0.8.1-bin-all\interpreter\spark\python\zeppelin_ipyspark.py", line 29
    port=${JVM_GATEWAY_PORT}, auth_token=gateway_secret, auto_convert=True))
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so can you help me?

Comment: Check on the line no 29 if all the round brackets are closed properly

Answer (score 0):

@LSS `zeppelin_ipyspark.py` is not a standalone script.
It is invoked internally from Zeppelin's java code as part of Ipython interpreter, where the python script is processed to replace these strings(like JVM_GATEWAY_PORT etc) with actual values.
You can check the code references: [1](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/python/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/python/IPythonInterpreter.java#L242), [2](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/interpreter/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/IPySparkInterpreter.java#L63)